# Criando Trigger para alterar status assim que deletar funcionário

Tags: sql, trigger

Estou criando uma trigger que no momento que deletar um funcionário ela mude o status de 1 (ativo) para 0(inativo) em seguida salve esta alteração em uma tabela (funcionariosdemitidos) para acessar caso precise, porém, estou com problemas. Assim que tento criar a trigger o SQL Server informa a seguinte mensagem

> Mensagem 213, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento TrigFuncionarioDemitido, Linha 23
>   O nome da coluna ou o número de valores fornecidos não corresponde à definição da tabela.
>   Citação

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrigFuncionarioDemitido
ON funcionarios
INSTEAD OF  DELETE
AS
BEGIN
       Begin Transaction F1
       -- DECLARAR UMA VARIมVEL
     DECLARE @id  INT
     -- ATRIBUIR VALOR A VARอAVEL @id
       SELECT @id =
                            (
                  SELECT D.id
                  FROM    deleted             AS D
                )
    -- 1) fazer o UPDATE na tabela de Funcionแrio
    -- atualizar o Status
    UPDATE funcionarios
    SET Status = 0
    WHERE  id = @id

    -- 2) FAZER UMA INSERวรO DO FUNCIONARIO DEMITIDO
    -- PARA A TBFUNICONARIO DEMITIDO
    INSERT INTO funcionariosdemitidos
    SELECT f.* , GETDATE ()
    FROM funcionarios AS f
    WHERE id = @id
    IF (@@ERROR = 0)
      begin
         commit transaction f1
       print 'Registro atualizado com sucesso'
     end
    ELSE
       begin
         rollback transaction f1
       print 'Registro nใo atualizado'
       end

END
```

Código do banco completo e trigger no link a seguir

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oruulm9n9crhdza/Codigo.txt

Comment: Andrey, obrigado pela ajuda na edição do post.

Comment: Cheque funcionariosdemitidos, se existe a tabela e se as colunas são as mesmas de funcionarios mais uma coluna de data, o erro parece estar aí.

Comment: Valeu Motta! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após observação do Motta adicionei o campo data na tabela funcionariosdemitidos e deu certo.

> Cheque funcionariosdemitidos, se existe a tabela e se as colunas são
>   as mesmas de funcionarios mais uma coluna de data, o erro parece estar
>   aí. –  Motta

No código eu estava adicionando o getdate(), porem, na tabela funcionariosdemitidos não tinha essa linhas. Feito isso a trigger rodou certinha.

Obrigado!

Comment: Diogo, não esqueça de marcar sua própria resposta como a correta!

Comment: Feito, Andrey! Obrigado também. Abraço

Comment: Ah, o Motta fica sem pontuação?

Comment: Se você quer que o Motta ganhe pontuação (é justo), escreva um comentário na sua pergunta citando o nome dele (com @Motta) pedindo pra ele transcrever seu comentário em forma de pergunta. Assim tu pode marcá-la como a correta e ele ganhará os pontos.

Comment: Por mim não, o próprio Diogo resolveu a bagaça, só dei um palpite feliz !!